# What is meant by $\infty^1$, $\infty^2$, $\infty^3$?

Tags: group-theory, notation

I find the notation $\infty^1$, $\infty^2$, $\infty^3$ in an old paper by Kasner [1].  The context is, for example, "...we obtain from a given system in general $\infty^3$ new systems" and "A turbine consists of $\infty^1$ elements whose points form a circle..."  What is the meaning of this $\infty^n$ notation?

[1] Kasner, Edward, "The Group of Turns and Slides and the Geometry of Turbines," Am. J. Math., Vol. 33, No. 1/4 (Jan., 1911), pp. 193-202.

Comment: I don't know, but does it seem from the context that $\infty^n$ could mean something like an $n$-dimensional space?

Comment: [Here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2369992?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) is the article on JSTOR (for other readers).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that "$\infty^n$" is Kasner's shorthand for "an $n$-dimensional manifold of".

Answer (score 1):

I find the notation somewhat bewildering. Without actually understanding what the author writes about, I have the strong impression that $\infty^n$ refers to a *geometric* "$n$-parameter" family of things — i.e. an $n$-dimensional space.

(I emphasize *geometric*, since the author does talk about $n$-parameter groups)

The best concrete conformation I have for this interpretation is the phrase

> ... the $\infty^3$ circles of a plane

since one can parametrize circles in the plane with three parameters; e.g. the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the origin along with the radius.